# Edit an embedded Document on the many side of one-to-many relationship in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am wondering how I can update an embedded document (in the MongoDB term) in an one-to-many relationship. For example, a blog can have many comments and those comments are embedded in a blog document. In the Java development space, shall I do remove a comment is going to be edited and insert an edited version of the comment back to the collection data type, a list, and call the save method in Spring Data MongoDB (that is the update method in MongoDB) since I can't identify the comment without a ID field? This question is based on an assumption that an embedded document doesn't come with a ID by design.

Comment: How are you going to remove the comment without knowing the ID?

Comment: Java List API has a method called remove(Object o). As long as I have a correct pair of hashCode and equals methods, the API method shall do the job.